# how to perform wavelet transform on time series speed signal

Tags: matlab, wavelet-transform

I have time vs velocity data. This should be used as my time series speed signal on which i have to perform continuous wavelet transform using matlab (wavelet toolbox). But I am not able to incorporate the time component. I am importing signal from workspace which is a nx1 array(velocity). Any clarification on how to incorporate time vs speed as my signal will be great. Thanks in advance...

Comment: `nx1` doesn't mean `n` values of velocity at different times?

Comment: actually i am able to give the velocity values at x - units (1,2,3...n). but i have to give the value of velocity at time (t = 15sec,30sec.... etc.) . can i do this with the help of sampling period which is available in the continuous wavelet transfor toolbox ?

Comment: you should post your code

Comment: `nx1` must be amplitude or voltage values, velocity of sound should be more or less constant as long as the medium does not change. Said more or less because it may change when there is a change in temperature/grains etc.. Time can be calculated from your sampling rate. For example, if you are samling ultrasonic signal at 100Mhz, the time interval between each neighbouring amlitude/voltage values will be 1/100,000,000 second, i.e. 10 nano second.

Comment: Also, as far as I know, wavelet transform is performed over time domain, i.e. time vs amplitude/voltage values.

Comment: If you know your sampling period, start time and n, then you can construct an nx1 vector containing the times: 
times = startTime:samplingPeriod:(startTime+(n-1)*samplingPeriod)